# Как сделать EXE из TornadoFX JAR?

Tags: javafx, intellij-idea, exe, tornadofx

У меня есть простой проект на JavaFX/TornadoFX на Windows, который собирается в JAR и корректно выполняется из-под IntelliJ IDEA и в установленной на моем компьютере JRE. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы этот проект мог выполняться на любом компьютере под Windows без предварительно установленной JRE.

Для этого в IntelliJ я создал сборку "JavaFx application" и настроил ее так, как написано в инструкции к TornadoFX:

[image: настройки проекта]

[image: настройки проекта]

Исполнимый файл собирается успешно, но когда я пытаюсь запустить его то выводится ошибка «No method main in class com/example/demo/app/MyApp.»

Я пытался добавить main в код проекта, как это написано в инструкции к TornadoFX, но не могу указать этот метод в настройках проекта - кнопка ОК не активна.

[image: настройки проекта, выбор главного класса]

Автоматически можно добавить только класс MyApp, но он разумеется метод main не содержит.

[image: настройки проекта, выбор главного класса]

Что я делаю не правильно и как мне всё-таки сделать исполнимый файл под Windows?

Вот код:

MyApp.kt

```
package com.example.demo.app

import com.example.demo.view.MainView
import tornadofx.App
import tornadofx.launch

class MyApp: App(MainView::class, Styles::class)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    launch<MyApp>(args)
}
```

Comment: launch4j поможет.

Comment: Можно попробовать добавить информацию о main через плагины в pom или руками в META-INF

Comment: launch4j - это только обертка, а мне хотелось бы таскать с собой и JRE, чтобы пользователю ничего отдельно ставить не надо было руками.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я ещё раз внимательно перечитал мануал к TornadoFX и увидел маленькую, но важную фразу: "Notice the Kt at the end.". Оказывается нужно было вручную дописать в поле "Application class" символы "Kt" в конец и всё заработало как я и хотел.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]